# Try Catch Like Exception Handling In Pl/Sql

Tags: plsql

In a procedure, I want to do logic unit 1, doesn't matter if it fails, execute logic unit 2

this seems like a typical try-catch scenario. but how can I do it in pl/sql?

```
create or replace
PACKAGE BUILD_PKG
AS
PROCEDURE reset_seq_and_truncate_tbl(
    p_seq_name   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_table_name IN VARCHAR2 );
END BUILD_PKG;
/
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY  BUILD_PKG
AS
BEGIN
PROCEDURE reset_seq_and_truncate_tbl(
    p_seq_name   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_table_name IN VARCHAR2 )
 IS
   l_val NUMBER;
 BEGIN
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE immediate 'truncate table ' || p_table_name;
   EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS 
        THEN dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
   END;

   BEGIN
     EXECUTE immediate 'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by 1 minvalue 0';
   EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS 
        THEN dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
   END; 
 END reset_seq_and_truncate_tbl;

END BUILD_PKG;
```

as you can see the second Exception block cause the problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Enclose the second `EXCEPTION` in `BEGIN..END` block. Try this way

```
PROCEDURE reset_seq_and_truncate_tbl(
    p_seq_name   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_table_name IN VARCHAR2 )
 IS
   l_val NUMBER;
 BEGIN
   EXECUTE immediate 'truncate table ' || p_table_name;
 EXCEPTION 
      WHEN OTHERS 
      THEN
      BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
        EXECUTE immediate 'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by 1 minvalue 0';
       --this would cause compilation error
       EXCEPTION 
            WHEN OTHERS 
            THEN dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
     END; 
 END reset_seq_and_truncate_tbl;
```

UPDATE in response to the comment

```
PROCEDURE reset_seq_and_truncate_tbl(
    p_seq_name   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_table_name IN VARCHAR2 )
 IS
   l_val NUMBER;
 BEGIN
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE immediate 'truncate table ' || p_table_name;
   EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS 
        THEN dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
   END;

   BEGIN
     EXECUTE immediate 'alter sequence ' || p_seq_name || ' increment by 1 minvalue 0';
   EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS 
        THEN dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE);
   END; 
 END reset_seq_and_truncate_tbl;
```

Comment: Almost exact to my answer. i'll delete mine.

Comment: sorry, I should'v made it more clear. execute logic 1, doesn't matter if it fails, execute logic 2

Comment: take a look at the second approach

Comment: I've assumed that some pl/sq code might be after the second instruction that have to be executed even if the second instruction fails.

Comment: doesn't work if I put it in a package body but it works as just defined as a procedure.

Comment: hi Nicholas, I have updated the code, its actually in a package. I tried the double begin-end it works, but not in a package, so wired....

Comment: It works OK even if the procedure is a part of the package. The only thing you need to do is delete first BEGIN in the package body specification.

Answer (score 1):

PROCEDURE (
     )
 IS

BEGIN

-- Logical Unit1
   BEGIN
     ...
   EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS 
        THEN ...
   END;

-- Logical Unit2
   BEGIN
     ...
   EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS 
        THEN ...
   END;

-- Final Exception Block 
 EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS 
        THEN ...

END ;