# Jump to next sql query if one query fails

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

I want to know that is it possible to create package of queries such that if any query fails then plsql developer should jump to next query and should not stop until all queries run and at the end it should display that which query failed.

For example I have set of 5 queries.

I created one package contains these 5 queries. Now I want to create that package such that if 3rd query fails while running, plsql developer shouldn't stop and should jump to 4th query and run all remaining queries. At the end of all queries result it should show '3rd query failed'

Comment: I think [Try Catch Like Exception Handling In Pl/Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527507/try-catch-like-exception-handling-in-pl-sql) this answer will help you. I used it worked for me

Comment: i think you should use go to statement.  with go to you can jump in query . Do you want that?

Comment: From the `plsqldeveloper` tag, can we assume that you are using Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Create queryExecutor proecure to take query as parameter.
Start of the procedure have audit log into one table.
After completion/Exception block update the audit log entry with completed/failed.
Call the queryExcutore using DBMS Scheduler. Each query will run independently.

Have while loop at ending to check whether all submitted jobs are with completed/failed status.. till the count is equal to job count submitted. You can run this checker. Once both are equal exit from the loop.

Answer (score -2):

you can use try catch.

here's the syntax

BEGIN TRY
     { sql_statement | statement_block }
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
END CATCH
[ ; ]

Comment: you can use this to avoid rollback once your query has a errors

Comment: the logic is already there, just look for the proper syntax that suits your needs

Comment: @Paras [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) is for Oracle and the solution above is for SQL Server, if that's what you meant.