# Checking execution of procedure (PL/SQL, Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure, oracle12c

I have below PL/SQL block:

```
Begin
   insert1();
   insert2();
   insert3();

   procedureTest();    
End
```

Each **insertTest** is making insert to some tables.

Now, if one of this procedure will not insert anything, my **procedureTest** should not execute.

How to do that?

Comment: You need t learn about transactions and `commit`.

Comment: handle the exceptions for each insert. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527507/try-catch-like-exception-handling-in-pl-sql

Comment: When the `insert1/2/3` procedures do not insert anything, is this an error condition within those procedures? If not, can they return row counts via an `out` parameter?

Comment: no is no error, I just want to somehow dont run procedureTest

Comment: In that case you need some test to check whether  `procedureTest` should be executed or not. Either count the rows in the tables, or have the `insert1/2/3` procedures pass something back that you can inspect and then decide whether or not to proceed.

Comment: can I use "SQL%ROWCOUNT" ?

Comment: Sure, though it matters where and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have two possibilities to check if the three procedures insert rows:

1) launch a query or call a function to select the count of rows expected to be inserted after each call;

2) store the result of the command `sql%rowcount`: this command returns the count of rows affected from preceeding `insert/update/delete` instruction.

**Note** that, for the 2nd option, if `insert1/2/3` insert rows using only one single insert instruction AND this single insert is the last statement of the procedure, then you can call `sql%rowcount` after the call to `insert1/2/3` in the following way:

```
declare
   ret NUMBER := 0;
Begin
   insert1();
   ret := sql%rowcount; -- counts rows inserted in insert1

   insert2();
   ret := ret + sql%rowcount; -- counts rows inserted in insert1 + insert2

   insert3();
   ret := ret + sql%rowcount; -- counts rows inserted in insert1 + insert2 + insert3

   if ret > 0 then
      procedureTest();
   end if;
End
```

Instead, if the three procedures use more than one insert statement each OR perform a select or any other instruction after the insert, you have to check `sql%rowcount` *inside* `insert1/2/3` immediately after each insert statement and return the sum of these results as output parameter (if `insert1/2/3` are procedures) or as return value (if `insert1/2/3` are functions).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think operator `+=` is not available in Oracle PL/SQL

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: you're right.. modified answer

Comment: This relies on the `insert1/2/3` procedures having the `insert select` statement as their last action. If someone adds logging or something to them then the logic is broken.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: I've specified it in my answer... :-)

Answer (score 1):

From this

> if one of this procedure will not insert anything

I understand you want to stop execution of the rest of the code. So, for this, a suggestion would be: in those functions insert1/2/3, return the number of rows affected with:

```
sql%rowcount
```

Notice that this function counts the number of rows affected, so to speak, it counts only with insert, update, and delete statements (not select), for select, you'd need a cursor, more information you can find here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=rows-affected

Then, as those functions return a value that, if have inserted anything will return a number > 0, then you can store then in a variable and check their values, if any of then is == 0, then return, otherwise, execute procedureTest(). To interrupt execution, you can use `return;`

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to have your `insert1/2/3` procedures return the number of rows inserted as `OUT` parameters, which you could then capture and examine in the calling procedure.

```
declare
    l_rowcount1 integer := 0;
    l_rowcount2 integer := 0;
    l_rowcount3 integer := 0;

    l_rowcount_total integer := 0;

    procedure insert1
        ( p_rowcount out integer )
    is
    begin
        insert into sometable(a, b, c)
        select x, y, z from somewhere
        where  whatever = somethingelse;

        p_rowcount := sql%rowcount;
    end insert1;

begin
    insert1(l_rowcount1);
    insert1(l_rowcount2);
    insert1(l_rowcount3);

    l_rowcount_total := l_rowcount1 + l_rowcount2 + l_rowcount3;

    if l_rowcount_total > 0 then
        do_something();
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure insert1 is
  o_error varchar2(150);
begin
  -- your statement 1
 exception when others then rollback; o_error := ' an error occured! '; raise_application_error(-20101,o_error);
end;
```

Create procedures `insert1` - `2` - `3` as preceding by iterating error code by one in every consecutive insert procedure as `-20002` & `-20003`, and statements `2` & `3`.

And call as you did before with a returning error argument:

```
Begin
   insert1;
   insert2;
   insert3;

   procedureTest();    
End
```

If any error raises, you'll see it as an alert and your program unit will stop running.

Comment: got your point, I can do that but if possible to "catch" the insert? like I want to know how many rows were inserted and the use "IF"

Comment: @4est as other friends told, you can count by sql%rowcount, but your question's text doesn't ask for it?(please edit your question with this extra information)