# PLSQL exception handling for retrieve custom message instead of exception details

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to handle the possible exceptions caught during the execution of a stored procedure - by using `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` code block - and return a *user-friendly* message (*instead of the details of the exception*).

This is the code of the stored procedured I'm working:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ProcessWork
  (
    V_USER      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    CV_1            IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
  AS
  V_TOTALREADED NUMBER(9):=0;
  V_DINITCOLLECTCOTDEC4023 DATE;
  V_MAX_COR_NCODE NUMBER(9,0):=0;
  V_LOG_NCODE NUMBER := 0; 
  V_ERRMSG VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);
  BEGIN
    -------------START - VALIDATIONS --------------

    -- DUPLICATED LINE:
    INSERT INTO TLOG_FILE_RETURN(LFR_NCODE,RECORD_LINE,LGR_CLOG_CAUSE)
    SELECT TMP.LFR_NCODE,TMP.RECORD_LINE,'DUPLICATED LINE'
    FROM TLOADED_FILE_RETURN TMP
    WHERE TMP.RECORD_LINE IS NOT NULL
          AND EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(TMP.LFR_NCODE) CONTEO
                      FROM TLOADED_FILE_RETURN TMI
                      WHERE TMI.RECORD_LINE = TMP.RECORD_LINE
                      HAVING COUNT(TMI.RECORD_LINE) > 1)
    ;
    
    -- STATE DOES NOT EXISTS:
    INSERT INTO TLOG_FILE_RETURN(LFR_NCODE,RECORD_LINE,LGR_CLOG_CAUSE)
    SELECT TMP.LFR_NCODE,TMP.RECORD_LINE,'STATE (' || TMP.RAS_NCODE || ') DOES NOT EXISTS.'
    FROM TLOADED_FILE_RETURN TMP
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM T_REJECT_AFF_STATE RAS
                      WHERE RAS.RAS_NCODE = TMP.RAS_NCODE)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TLOG_FILE_RETURN TLOG WHERE TLOG.LFR_NCODE = TMP.LFR_NCODE);
    
    -- [other data validations here removed for brevity]

    -------------END - VALIDATIONS --------------

    -- NOTE HERE: Raise intentional exception for sampling:
    SELECT 1/0 
    INTO V_COUNTERROR 
    FROM DUAL;

    -- Table that stores all validated data:
    INSERT INTO TLOAD_FILE_RETURN
    (
        LFR_NCODE,
        LFR_NCODE_PROCESS,
        NSO_CLEGALCODE,
        NSO_NCODE,
        RAO_NCODE,
        RAS_NCODE,
        INT_CKEY,
        INT_NCODE,
        RAF_CTELEPHONE,
        RAT_NCODE,
        RAF_OBSERVATION_ANALYST,
        RCA_NCODE,
        RAF_CNOVELTYCAUSE,
        RECORD_LINE
    )
    SELECT
      TMP.LFR_NCODE,
      REPLACE(TMP.LFR_NCODE_PROCESS,' ',''),
      REPLACE(TMP.NSO_CLEGALCODE,' ',''),
      REPLACE(NOV.NSO_NCODE,' ',''),
      REPLACE(TMP.RAO_NCODE,' ',''),
      REPLACE(TMP.RAS_NCODE,' ',''),
      REPLACE(TMP.INT_CKEY,' ',''),
      REPLACE(IT.INT_NCODE,' ',''),
      REPLACE(TMP.RAF_CTELEPHONE,' ',''),
      REPLACE(TMP.RAT_NCODE,' ',''),
      REPLACE(TMP.RAF_OBSERVATION_ANALYST,' ',''),
      REPLACE(TMP.RCA_NCODE,' ',''),
      REPLACE(TMP.RAF_CNOVELTYCAUSE,' ',''),
      TMP.RECORD_LINE
    FROM TLOADED_FILE_RETURN TMP
    JOIN T_NOVELTY_SOURCE NOV  ON NOV.NSO_CLEGAL_CODE=TMP.NSO_CLEGALCODE
    JOIN T_ident_type ITY ON ITY.ITY_CSHORTNAME=TMP.ITY_CSHORTNAME
    JOIN T_INTERMEDIARY IT ON IT.INT_CKEY=TMP.INT_CKEY
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TLOG_FILE_RETURN TLOG WHERE TLOG.LFR_NCODE=TMP.LFR_NCODE)
      ;

    -- Count of valid records:
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO V_TOTALREADED FROM TLOAD_FILE_RETURN;

    -- If valid records are found, start process:
    IF(NVL(V_TOTALREADED,0) > 0) THEN
      BEGIN
          -- MERGE para update "_NCODE" relational-fields:
          MERGE INTO TLOAD_FILE_RETURN INF
          USING (
                SELECT TMP.LFR_NCODE,
                       NSO.NSO_NCODE,
                       ITY.ITY_NCODE,
                       INE.INT_NCODE
                FROM TLOAD_FILE_RETURN TMP INNER JOIN T_NOVELTY_SOURCE NSO
                ON TMP.NSO_CLEGALCODE = NSO.NSO_CLEGAL_CODE INNER JOIN T_IDENT_TYPE ITY
                ON TMP.ITY_CSHORTNAME = ITY.ITY_CSHORTNAME
                INNER JOIN T_IDENT_TYPE ITY
                ON TMP.ITY_CSHORTNAME = ITY.ITY_CSHORTNAME
                INNER JOIN T_INTERMEDIARY INE
                ON TMP.INT_CKEY = INE.INT_CKEY
          ) SRC
          ON (INF.LFR_NCODE=SRC.LFR_NCODE)
          WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
                       INF.NSO_NCODE = SRC.NSO_NCODE,
                       INF.ITY_NCODE = SRC.ITY_NCODE,
                       INF.INT_NCODE = SRC.INT_NCODE
                    ;
                    
          -- Other MERGEs code removed for brevity.

          -- Data inserction to business tables:
          INSERT INTO T_REJECTED_AFFILIAT
          (
               RPT_NCODE, 
               RAF_CIDENTIFICATIONTYPE_HOLDER, 
               RAF_CIDENTIFICATIONNUMB_HOLDER,
               RAF_OBSERVATION_ANALYST, 
               RAF_OBSERVATION_ADVISER
          )
            SELECT 4, 
                   TMP.ITY_NCODE, 
                   TMP.PER_CIDENTIFICATIONNUMBER, 
                   TMP.RAF_OBSERVATION_ANALYST, 
                   NULL
            FROM TLOAD_FILE_RETURN TMP
            WHERE TMP.LFR_NCODE_PROCESS = 1;

            INSERT INTO T_REJECT_CAUSE_BY_REJECT_AFFI (RAF_NCODE, RCA_NCODE)
            SELECT T.RAF_NCODE, T.RCA_NCODE
            FROM (
                 SELECT RAF.RAF_NCODE, TMP.RCA_NCODE
                 FROM T_REJECTED_AFFILIAT RAF JOIN TLOAD_FILE_RETURN TMP
                 ON RAF.NSO_NCODE = (SELECT RAF.NSO_NCODE FROM T_NOVELTY_SOURCE NSO WHERE NSO.NSO_CLEGAL_CODE = TMP.NSO_CLEGALCODE) /* Tipo de fuente. */
                 AND RAF.RAF_CAPPLICATIONCODE = TMP.RAF_NAPPLICATIONCODE /* Número de formulario / solicitud. */
                 AND RAF.RAT_NCODE = TMP.RAT_NCODE /* Tipo de registro. */
                 WHERE TMP.LFR_NCODE_PROCESS = 1
            ) T
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM T_REJECT_CAUSE_BY_REJECT_AFFI RCB
                              WHERE RCB.RAF_NCODE =  T.RAF_NCODE
                              AND RCB.RCA_NCODE = T.RCA_NCODE)
            UNION
            SELECT TMP.RAF_NCODE, TMP.RCA_NCODE
            FROM TLOAD_FILE_RETURN TMP
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM T_REJECT_CAUSE_BY_REJECT_AFFI RCB
                              WHERE RCB.RAF_NCODE =  TMP.RAF_NCODE
                              AND RCB.RCA_NCODE = TMP.RCA_NCODE)
            AND TMP.LFR_NCODE_PROCESS = 2;

          -- Apply all changes made so far:
          COMMIT;

            DECLARE
            CURSOR C_LOAD_FILE_RET IS
                SELECT TMP.RAF_NCODE, TMP.PREV_RAS_NCODE, TMP.RAS_NCODE, SYSDATE, V_USER
                FROM TLOAD_FILE_RETURN TMP
                WHERE TMP.LFR_NCODE_PROCESS = 2
                AND NVL(TMP.RAS_NCODE, 0) <> NVL(TMP.PREV_RAS_NCODE, 0)
                AND TMP.RAF_NCODE IS NOT NULL
                AND NSO_NCODE = 35 -- 7W
                AND RAT_NCODE = 10 -- AFILIACION EN RECORD_LINE
                ;

            TYPE TBL_LOAD_FILE_RET IS TABLE OF C_LOAD_FILE_RET%ROWTYPE
            INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

            TAB_LOAD_FILE_RET TBL_LOAD_FILE_RET;

            BEGIN
            OPEN C_LOAD_FILE_RET;
                LOOP

                TAB_LOAD_FILE_RET.DELETE;

                FETCH C_LOAD_FILE_RET BULK COLLECT INTO TAB_LOAD_FILE_RET LIMIT 10000;

                BEGIN
                FORALL I IN INDICES OF TAB_LOAD_FILE_RET
                UPDATE T_REJECTED_AFFILIAT
                SET RAS_NCODE = TAB_LOAD_FILE_RET(I).RAS_NCODE
                WHERE RAF_NCODE = TAB_LOAD_FILE_RET(I).RAF_NCODE;

                COMMIT;
                EXIT WHEN C_LOAD_FILE_RET%NOTFOUND;
            EXCEPTION
              WHEN OTHERS THEN
                EXIT;
            END;
            END LOOP;
            CLOSE C_LOAD_FILE_RET;
        END;
       RETURN;
      END;
    END IF;

    -- Start exception code-block: 
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
       V_ERRMSG:=SQLERRM||'-'||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE;
       ROLLBACK;
       
       /* Insert exception details in log table for futher investigation: */
       PROCLOG(2, V_LOG_NCODE, SUBSTR(V_ERRMSG,1,250), V_USER, CV_1);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Check error code # ' || TO_CHAR(V_LOG_NCODE));  
       
       /* Return error for show to user: */
       OPEN CV_1 FOR
            SELECT
                   CAST(0 AS NUMBER(9,0)) TOTAL_LOADED,
                   CAST(0 AS NUMBER(9,0)) TOTAL_SUCCESS,
                   CAST(0 AS NUMBER(9,0)) TOTAL_ERROR,
                   '.' FOLDERLOGS,
                   '.' FILE_NAMELOG,
                   /* This is the custom message: */
                   'An unexpected error ocurred while processing the data - error # ' || TO_CHAR(V_LOG_NCODE) MSG_ERROR 
                FROM DUAL;
       RETURN;
    -- End exception code-block: 

  END;
```

And the results are:

```
PL/SQL procedure finished correctly. 
ERROR # ORA-01476:  divisor is equal to zero: line 41

SQLERRM: ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE: ORA-06512: line 41
```

The problem I'm facing is that the following SQL code is not returning the cursor called `CV_1` and keep showing Oracle-error details.

The desired result should be that this code-block should not return the Oracle-error details, but instead, the sample message saved in the `V_ERRMSG` variable.

[This sample on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=abe05c6dd85f828f75ba257d6e423b00) is a reduced sample for testing, but I can't say what I'm doing wrong in both scenarios (*i.e, executing this code on SQL Developer and in dbfiddle.uk*).

Comment: `cv_1` is a local variable so it goes out of scope once the anonymous block completes regardless of whether the block enters an exception handler.  Perhaps you really want to create a stored procedure that has an `out` parameter of type `sys_refcursor`?  Same with `v_errmsg`-- if you want that to be returned to the caller, you'd want a stored procedure with an `out` parameter.  Using return codes rather than throwing exceptions to indicate that a procedure encountered problems, though, is generally frowned upon.  It makes your code far more complex.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to throw a custom exception with a custom message?

Comment: @JustinCave thanks for the comments, you're correct. `CV_1` is an parameter of the stored procedure - `CV_1 IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR`. The code I posted is an sample, I could add the replica of the stored procedure I'm working - if it is needed for improve the question overall - I want to *(once the SP ends and if it catches an exception)*, return a custom message.

Comment: Is `v_errmsg` also an `out` parameter?  If the code you're actually using is a stored procedure and that is necessary to replicate the problem you're actually having, which it appears to be, then, yes, updating your code to be a procedure would be very helpful along with showing us how you're calling that code.  Otherwise, we have to make a bunch of assumptions which may or may not be true for you.

Comment: @JustinCave question edited. I'm calling this code from a C# application and I can't add details from that layer (C#) due it's a lot of code, unfortunately. If I compile for debug this stored procedure and execute it as debug mode (*Control+Shift+F10* in SQL Developer), the result "when no error ocurred" is an table [as is shown in this sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuRp3.png) - unfortunately, I'm having more troubles with the connection of the debug and well sorry for so many excuses, but, if you need more info. I'll update. Thanks.

Comment: It's still useful to simplify the problem-- include all the code that is actually necessary to replicate the problem but no more.  My vague guess is that you want something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a865093132d49345115aeeea79320399 but I still don't understand exactly what you want to happen.  The procedure can't return `v_errMsg` because `v_errMsg` isn't a parameter.  I'm not sure if you actually want `v_errMsg` to be returned or if you want it to be a column in the `cv_1` cursor.

Comment: I think you are missing just a `/` at the end of your script. After adding a `/` it is working fine. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2131c6a6b5bfbc45e313a31367c4a358

Comment: @AnkitBajpai thanks; after I check the source code, there is no `/` character.

Comment: So, does this works for you? or you still need a solution?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I still looking for a solution.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I'm still looking for a solution; the best way I can describe my issue with this code is that I want to handle exceptions like in C# - by using `try/catch`. This [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12527507/12511801) is what I'm looking for, but, I tested and it keeps throwing the oracle-exception details; I need to those oracle-details are saved in a separated table and the execution of the procedure continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking more closely the source code, I did noted certain elements:

- The `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` code block is nested inside the `BEGIN-END` of the `IF(NVL(V_TOTALREADED,0) > 0) THEN` code block, hence, if no exception is catched  *in the whole code* the exception is raised, but not handled as intended.
- Outside of the `ProcessWork` procedure, the application checks if there are any data inserted in the `TLOG_FILE_RETURN` table  - *which is used for insert custom/business validations* - This is made by doing a `COUNT()` of the records in `TLOG_FILE_RETURN` table. This count is made only once - *previous to call `ProcessWork` procedure* -.

I had to make the following changes:

- Move the `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` code block outside of the `BEGIN-END` code block *(described in previous lines in this answer)* - leaving the `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` at the end of the `ProcessWork` procedure.
- Make a second `COUNT()` of the records in `TLOG_FILE_RETURN` table - *after* call `ProcessWork` procedure.
- Remove the `RETURN` keyword of the the `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` code block.

With these changes, I get the desired results (*save the oracle-details of the raised exception in a separated table, set an user-friendly message for return and continue with the execution of the program*).

The modified code is shown below:

> NOTE: This code is a simplified version of the `ProcessWork` procedure
> with the changes described in this answer.

---

```
create table BH_LOG (id number(9, 0), error_msg varchar2(1000));
```

```
✓
```

```
DECLARE 
  V_COUNTERROR NUMBER :=0;
  CV_1          SYS_REFCURSOR;
  V_ERRMSG            VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR);--

  --STATISTICS: 
    V_TOTAL_LOADED              NUMBER(9,0) := 0;
    V_TOTAL_SUCCESS             NUMBER(9,0) := 0;
    V_TOTAL_ERROR                 NUMBER(9,0) := 0;

  V_FOLDERNAME    VARCHAR2(50) := 'SAMPLE';
  V_FOLDERLOGS    VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT V_FOLDERNAME || '\Logs';
  V_FILE_NAMELOG     VARCHAR2(50):= 'FileResult_' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yyyymmddhh24miss')  ||'.TXT';--
BEGIN
     BEGIN
        /*
         SELECT (1) CONTEO
         INTO V_COUNTERROR
         FROM T_BH_LOG_FILE_RETURN;

         FOR GENERATE ORA-01403 ERROR:
         */

         SELECT 1/0 
         INTO V_COUNTERROR 
         FROM DUAL;

        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
          --V_ERRMSG:=SQLERRM||'-'||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE;
          V_ERRMSG:='An error ocurred, please try again';-- Just an example.
          ROLLBACK;
          /*OPEN CV_1 FOR
               SELECT
                      CAST(0 AS NUMBER(9,0)) TOTAL_LOADED,
                      CAST(0 AS NUMBER(9,0)) TOTAL_SUCCESS,
                      CAST(0 AS NUMBER(9,0)) TOTAL_ERROR,
                      '.' FOLDERLOGS,
                      '.' FILE_NAMELOG,
                      V_ERRMSG
                   FROM DUAL;

                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR # ' || V_ERRMSG);
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLERRM: ' || SQLERRM);
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE: ' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);*/
          
          INSERT INTO BH_LOG (id, error_msg) 
          VALUES (1, V_ERRMSG); 
     END;
     OPEN CV_1 FOR
        SELECT
           V_TOTAL_LOADED TOTAL_LOADED,
           V_TOTAL_SUCCESS TOTAL_SUCCESS,
           V_TOTAL_ERROR TOTAL_ERROR,
           V_FOLDERLOGS FOLDERLOGS,
           V_FILE_NAMELOG FILE_NAMELOG,
           V_ERRMSG ERROMSG
        FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

```
 1 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM BH_LOG;
```

```
ID | ERROR_MSG                         
-: | :---------------------------------
 1 | An error ocurred, please try again
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=64c30a43ab70d648e151652fde118f12)*